# Joining three tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables:

**Houses Table**

```
id    title       description
--------------------------
1    Big House    Very big house
2    Small House  Very small house
```

**Rooms Table**

```
id    title        room_status
--------------------------
1     Green  room  24
2     Yellow room  25
3     Blue   room  24
```

**Houses_Rooms Table**

```
id   house_id     room_id
-------------------------
1    1            1
2    2            3
3    1            2
```

I have **room status** 24, for example.

I need get all houses from **Houses Table** that contains **rooms** with **room_status** = 24. But, if **house** has **rooms** with different **room_status** we do not need to choose this house.

I build some query and i use `WHERE house.id IN (SELECT ...)`. It works, but returns houses with same **room_status**, because `IN`.

Comment: So you want all houses that have a room with status = 24, unless they also have a status <> 24? i.e. in the scenario above you expect only house id 2 to be returned

Comment: If I understand correctly, a given room can only belong to 1 specific House. Therefore the satus of a room is a property of the room, and you only need 2 tables: Houses and Rooms (the later with a HouseId field). In other words, your schema sucks :-)

Comment: Quote [@Thorsten Kettner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49924243/4365678):You seem to want houses where all rooms have status 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want houses where all rooms have status 24.

`WHERE house.id IN (SELECT ...)` is a good idea. Now you need a subquery that only contains houses with only status-24 rooms.

```
select *
from houses
where id in
(
  select hr.house_id
  from houses_rooms hr
  join rooms r on r.id = hr.room_id
  group by hr.house_id
  having min(r.room_status) = 24
     and max(r.room_status) = 24
);
```

However, as it is unlikely that a house has no rooms at all, we can simply exclude houses with non-status-24 rooms instead:

```
select *
from houses
where id not in
(
  select house_id
  from houses_rooms
  where room_id in (select id from rooms where status <> 24)
);
```

Comment: Oh, i did not think about **having**, thanks it works!

Comment: I don't see any array here. You want an information on the rooms per house, so you group by house and check the accumulated room info. This is probably the best way to solve this, provided we need to check that a house has at least one status-24 room. Otherwise my other query is much better. An alternative to the aggregation (and the straight-forward Approach at that) would be one `IN` query for status-24 houses and one `NOT IN` query for non-status-24 houses.

Answer (score 0):

The below query selects all houses that have rooms with room_status = 24, but excludes houses that also have a room_status <> 24. It can probably be further optimized but my SQL is a little rusty:

```
select h.*
from houses h
  join houses_rooms hr on h.id = hr.house_id
  join rooms r on hr.room_id = r.id
where r.room_status = 24
  and h.id not in (
    select h.id
    from houses h
      join houses_rooms hr on h.id = hr.house_id
      join rooms r on hr.room_id = r.id
    where r.room_status <> 24
  );
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1864a6/6)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a sub-query for this kind of query.

```
SELECT
    HR.ID
    ,H.Title
    ,H.Description
    ,R.Title
FROM #House_Room HR
INNER JOIN #Houses H on HR.HouseID = h.ID
INNER JOIN #Rooms R on HR.RoomID = r.ID
WHERE R.RoomStatus = 24
```

Returns:

```
1   |  Big House    |  Very big house    |  Green room
2   |  Small House  |  Very small house  |  Blue room
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Houses A JOIN Houses_Rooms B
ON A.id=B.house_id JOIN (SELECT * FROM Rooms  WHERE room_status=24) C
ON C.id=B.room_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work because it uses `JOINS` to get those that have a room with `room_status = 24` and then uses `NOT IN` to rule out those that have other `room statuses`

```
SELECT * FROM Houses_Rooms hr
JOIN Houses h on hr.house_id = h.id
JOIN Rooms r on hr.room_id = r.id
WHERE r.room_status = 24
AND h.id NOT IN(
   SELECT h.house_id FROM Houses_Rooms h
   JOIN Rooms r on h.room_id = r.id 
   WHERE r.room_status <> 24  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select houses.title as 'house name'
From houses, rooms,houses_rooms
where houses.id=houses_rooms.house_id
and rooms.id=houses_rooms.room_id
and rooms.room_status=24
```

try this..am not 100% sure..i usually dont use joins.